# Stored Procedure Messages output to file

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Platform: SQL Server 2012

I have two stored procedures that take in a registration number and then based off that registration number, it prints out a bunch of HTML and XML.  In the proc is a bunch of print statements that spit out in the Messages area when it is run in SSMS.

It works great, I don't really like that it is designed this way but I inherited and they want it working.

I want this procedure to run and spit out the messages content into a file.  Ideally it would also rename the file the registration number after it ran.

Long story short, can out output the Messages portion of a SQL statement to a file.

SSIS? Or some simple BCP stored procedure command? Anybody run into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replaced all PRINT statements with SELECT statements and then sent each SELECT statement to a table.  We then pull on that table to properly build out an HTM file using SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `execute spWriteStringToFile` .
Found this here: https://www.simple-talk.com/code/WorkingWithFiles/spWriteStringTofile.txt

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spWriteStringToFile
 (
@String Varchar(max), --8000 in SQL Server 2000
@Path VARCHAR(255),
@Filename VARCHAR(100)

--
)
AS
DECLARE  @objFileSystem int
        ,@objTextStream int,
        @objErrorObject int,
        @strErrorMessage Varchar(1000),
        @Command varchar(1000),
        @hr int,
        @fileAndPath varchar(80)

set nocount on

select @strErrorMessage='opening the File System Object'
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OACreate  'Scripting.FileSystemObject' , @objFileSystem OUT

Select @FileAndPath=@path+'\'+@filename
if @HR=0 Select @objErrorObject=@objFileSystem , @strErrorMessage='Creating file "'+@FileAndPath+'"'
if @HR=0 execute @hr = sp_OAMethod   @objFileSystem   , 'CreateTextFile'
    , @objTextStream OUT, @FileAndPath,2,True

if @HR=0 Select @objErrorObject=@objTextStream, 
    @strErrorMessage='writing to the file "'+@FileAndPath+'"'
if @HR=0 execute @hr = sp_OAMethod  @objTextStream, 'Write', Null, @String

if @HR=0 Select @objErrorObject=@objTextStream, @strErrorMessage='closing the file "'+@FileAndPath+'"'
if @HR=0 execute @hr = sp_OAMethod  @objTextStream, 'Close'

if @hr<>0
    begin
    Declare 
        @Source varchar(255),
        @Description Varchar(255),
        @Helpfile Varchar(255),
        @HelpID int

    EXECUTE sp_OAGetErrorInfo  @objErrorObject, 
        @source output,@Description output,@Helpfile output,@HelpID output
    Select @strErrorMessage='Error whilst '
            +coalesce(@strErrorMessage,'doing something')
            +', '+coalesce(@Description,'')
    raiserror (@strErrorMessage,16,1)
    end
EXECUTE  sp_OADestroy @objTextStream
EXECUTE sp_OADestroy @objTextStream
```

Full article about it: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/